# CMake how to install shared STL libraries for Android?

Tags: android, cmake

According to the Android NDK documentation (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/BuildSystemMaintainers.md#STL).

"If using the shared variant, libc++_shared.so must be included in the APK."

Therefore as part of my CMake installation I'd like to install `libc++_shared.so` during my CMake installation if `CMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE` is equal to `c++_shared`.

I tried using `install(RUNTIME_DEPENDENCY_SET` but it doesn't seem to work with Android builds. As of CMake `3.27`.

> Note that file(GET_RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES) only supports collecting the runtime dependencies for Windows, Linux and macOS platforms, so install(RUNTIME_DEPENDENCY_SET) has the same limitation.

I have a workaround involving a python script to find the appropriate `libc++_shared.so` for the ABI I'm compiling against. But I'm hoping for a more elegant solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with:

NOTES:

- `abis.json` is parsed to get the triple since the CMake Android toolchain doesn't provide it. This approach is robust enough to handle future ABI(s).
- Requires at least CMake `3.19` due to `string(JSON` usage
- `CMAKE_SYSROOT` is set by the android toolchain to the appropriate location

Supporting documetnation:

- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/BuildSystemMaintainers.md#architectures

  - `abis.json` lets us get query the triple based on `CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI`
- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/BuildSystemMaintainers.md#STL

  - "This library is installed to `<NDK>/sysroot/usr/lib/<triple>`."

```
if ("${CMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE}" MATCHES "shared")
    file(READ "${CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK}/meta/abis.json" JSON_FILE)
    string(JSON TRIPLE GET "${JSON_FILE}" "${CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI}" "triple")
    install(FILES "${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/lib/${TRIPLE}/libc++_shared.so" DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}")
endif()
```

EDIT:

It seems like the current idiomatic answer is to use the Android Gradle Plugin to handle this for you.

Link to relevant conversation with an Android NDK developer: https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/1905

So the above code is only useful if you don't want to use the Android Gradle Plugin.